# integrated addresses monero javascript

Tags: integrated-address, javascript, library

my question are 2 :

how to generate monero address from bip39 words ( i am using react so i need a react compatible code )

how to generate integrated addresses  using JavaScript ( again react compatible )

Comment: Several duplicates, take your pick: https://monero.stackexchange.com/search?q=bip39